# How can I use an SDF instead of a URDF with gazebo in ros2 humble?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble, robot-state-publisher, sdf

Im using Gazebo 11 on ROS2 Humble.

I want to use an existing model of the polaris_ranger_xp900, by Cole Biesemeyer and Nate Koenig.

I want to spawn the model, add some ackerman gazebo plugins (maybe write one for myself) and test some of my navigation and control algorithms.

I managed to spawn the model through python launch file. the problem is that I dont know how to use the same SDF file with robot_state_publisher.

I couldn't find any complete examples for ROS2 so the question is if its even possible to use an SDF model to do what I wish? Or am I have to generate a complete URDF file so I could use robot_state_publisher?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [sdformat_urdf](https://github.com/ros/sdformat_urdf/) package to do this. [Here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/ros2_interop) is a tutorial written with the new Gazebo (Harmonic) in mind, but it should work similarly for Gazebo11.